# CocoaPods: build is success but color is red

Tags: ios, cocoapods

We are very confusing because the build completes successfully even though the label color is red. Please take a look screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

The base SDK is iOS7.1.

How can we fix this issue?

Comment: Do you try `pod install` and `pod update`?

Comment: It's the same in my pod projects, and it all works. Maybe its for not having multiple frameworks in the project. Did you check the pod is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. Providing your project builds and runs normally it's absolutely nothing to worry about.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Where are the compiled frameworks?